# MkDocs with mkdocstrings fails to serve with "Could not collect" error

Tags: python, mkdocs

I am using the Python MkDocs tool to build API documentation extracted directly from the source using the MkDocs mkdocstrings extension.

When I run the `mkdocs serve` command inside my project (in the directory which contains the `mkdocs.yml` file), the command fails with a `ERROR    -  Could not collect 'cpinotify'` error.

```
aUser@aMachine:~/notify2nats$ mkdocs serve
INFO     -  Building documentation...
INFO     -  Cleaning site directory
ERROR    -  mkdocstrings.extension: Error while loading JSON:

            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File
            "/home/aUser/.local/pipx/venvs/mkdocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mkdocstrings/handlers/python.py",
            line 206, in collect
                result = json.loads(stdout)
              File
            "/home/aUser/.asdf/installs/python/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py",
            line 346, in loads
                return _default_decoder.decode(s)
              File
            "/home/aUser/.asdf/installs/python/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py",
            line 337, in decode
                obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
              File
            "/home/aUser/.asdf/installs/python/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py",
            line 355, in raw_decode
                raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
            json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
ERROR    -  Error reading page 'API.md':
ERROR    -  Could not collect 'cpinotify'

Aborted with a BuildError!
```

My `docs/API.md` file which contains the MkDocs mkdocstrings command is:

```
# Test

::: cpinotify
```

(Where `cpinotify` is the name of the Python package from which the mkdocstrings documentation is to be extracted).

---

Versions:

- Python v3.9.6
- MkDocs v1.2.2
- mkdocstrings v0.15.2
- Ubuntu 20.04
- asdf v0.8.1-a1ef92a (to virtualize Python versions)
- pipx v0.16.3 (to virtualize installed Python packages/commands)

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Do not use the Python `argparser` **at the top level** in any module.

---

After some work (hacking the mkdocstrings code to understand what was happening)... I identified that (in my case) the problem was that my `cpinotify` code was using the Python `argparse` library **at the top level** in the `cpinotify/cpinotify.py` module.

The mkdocstrings code uses the `pytkdocs` command to extract the information it will use to build the documentation from the relevant Python code. The mkdocstrings code runs `pytkdocs` as an external process, feeding the required package information as JSON on `pytkdocs` stdin, and expects the results as JSON on `pytkdocs` stdout.

`pytkdocs` actually **imports** the code to be documented. Since both my `cpinotify` code as well as `pytkdocs` uses the `argparse` library, our two uses were conflicting and resulting in an error message and no JSON for the mkdocstrings extension to load.

While the Python `argparse` documentation shows examples where the `argparser` is created **at the top level**, this use at the **top level** when imported by `pytkdocs` was changing the `pytkdocs` expected command line options, causing `pytkdocs` to fail with no output.

---

**Solution:** Once I moved my use of the `argparse` library *inside* the `cpinotify.cli` method, my use of `argparse` was no longer being called when imported, and so was no longer changing `pytkdocs` expected command line arguments.

Having made this change to my code, the `pktdocs` command started working as expected and the `mkdocs serve` command worked with no errors producing the documentation I expected.

---

**Note**: the actual errors in my question (above) came from the fact that `pytkdocs` had failed to provide any output -- so mkdocstrings will provide similar failure reports any time that `pytkdocs` fails with no output.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed as of `mkdocstrings[python]>=0.18`, which uses `griffe` as its docs collector instead of `pytkdocs`, and by default does not execute the code being documented.

Migration notes: https://mkdocstrings.github.io/handlers/overview/#migrate-to-the-experimental-python-handler

Changelog: https://mkdocstrings.github.io/changelog/#0180-2022-02-06

Griffe and mkdocstrings 0.18 still don't (as of 2022-03-21) support all of the features that the older versions of mkdocstrings supported, such as element filtering. That said, the newer version come with numerous advantages, so I would recommend migrating over if possible now.